# iOS : Testflight No build available for external testers

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

I am using testflight as a beta testing tool for my app.
I have uploaded the build but invitation are successfully sent to the internal testers but no invitations are sent to external tester.

Below image shows both the groups has been invited
[image: This image shows both the groups has been invited]

And this image shows that no build available for external testers
[image: This image shows no build available for external testers]

Can anyone help me how I can get through with this?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

External Testers can only test builds that have passed Apple’s Beta Review process (similar to the App Store Review process). Each new version of the App must go through this process, however subsequent builds for the same version will not require review once the initial review process succeeds.

Internal Testers do not have this limitation.

Since it’s not exactly obvious, you can trigger a TestFlight build to be submitted for the Beta App Review process by adding an external tester to the build. Doing so will immediately change the status to Waiting for Review, once Apple reviews the beta version of the app the status will change again and you’ll get an email saying it’s ready for testing, and the previously selected External Testers will be able to access the build.

Comment: How time dose it take for Beta App Review?

Comment: I need add external tester to the build, but I the build pass beta app review to add external testers... I lose :c

Answer (score 19):

OK - this seems really silly but...

If external testers are added to a team before the build has been beta reviewed, they are "stuck" in a "No Build Available" status. Even after when Apple has reviewed and released the build for testing.

As Alpaslan Firat mentions - The easiest way to resolve this is to:

1. Remove tester from the group (can select >1 by using "Edit") - do not delete the Tester
2. Add back all of the testers to the group

App Store Connect then recognizes that there is a build waiting to be tested and sends the invitation.

The original question was asked a year ago - you would have thought that this would have been addressed by now.

Comment: Thank you for this! I was wondering why they were stuck in "No Builds Available", but it was because the testers were already there before the first build was approved. I cannot believe that Apple has not fixed this.

Comment: So, my app status still in review my external testers will have a status of NO BUILDS AVAILABLE? when this will change

Comment: Apple turned around the beta review of our app in less than 24h. After that, removing the testers and adding them again will trigger the email invite

Comment: This issue seems to still be affecting external testers on TestFlight builds. Removing the testers and re-adding them fixed the issue for a build I submitted yesterday.

Comment: Just an update: I still ran into this problem in August 2021, and this was the workaround that helped me.

Answer (score 6):

sometimes it is necessary to remove and readd the group of external testers.

Answer (score 3):

Go to TestFlight -> Builds -> Add the testing build by clicking plus icon.

Write the testing task for external tester. Then -> Submit it.

Then testing invitation email will be delivered to external tester.

Comment: I did same steps To send Testflight invitation for external tester whose status shows "No Builds Available" and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error was showing because the email was not registered as an Apple Id. So I added a new email (Apple Id) and now the build is available.

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to the main Apple Developer Page where it says Users and Access and first add all the users and emails there. And then when you go into the App and build in testflight. Click Add group Instead of individual Users and then just like add the users to the group and you're good.

Answer (score -2):

There are a few reasons why external testers may see a "builds not available" message during Test Flight:

- The build has not yet been uploaded to TestFlight.
- The build has been uploaded to TestFlight, but it hasn't been processed by Apple yet. This may take a few hours.
- The tester is not invited to the test group that contains the build.
- The tester's invitation to the test group has expired.
- Tester's Apple ID is not valid.
- There is a problem with the test flight itself.

To fix the problem, you can try the following:

- Make sure the build is uploaded to TestFlight and processed by Apple. You can check this by going to the Test Flight tab in App Store Connect and looking at the build status.
- Make sure the tester is invited to the test group that contains the build. You can check this by going to the TestFlight tab in App Store Connect and looking at the members of the test group.
- Make sure the tester's invitation to the test group has not expired. Invitations expire after 90 days.
- Make sure the tester's Apple ID is valid. You can check this by asking the tester to login to App Store Connect.
- Try restarting the tester's device.
- Try logging out of TestFlight and logging in again.
- If you still have problems, contact Apple Support for assistance.

Here are some additional tips for troubleshooting TestFlight issues:

- Make sure the tester is using the latest version of TestFlight.
- Make sure the tester's device is connected to the Internet.
- Try disabling the tester's VPN or firewall.
- Try restarting the tester's router.
- If you still have problems, you can try creating a new test group and adding the build and testers to the new group. You can try deleting the build and uploading it again.

Comment: Are you aware of our [policy forbidding AI-generated answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/354577)?