# TestFlight: Is fully submitting to the App Store required to add external testers?

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight, beta

We have an alpha (pre-beta) version of an app in development that we would like to distribute to five external testers via TestFlight, so they can give us feedback as we develop.

We uploaded the build and added our external testers. Upon doing so, the TestFlight build was marked Waiting for Review, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51086410/1337422).

Then it got rejected. Now, when trying to Submit again, it's asking for everything needed to submit to the App Store (screenshots, etc).

**This is a beta - not ready for the App Store.**

*How do I resubmit for a TestFlight beta review?*

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the build was rejected for TestFlight then you will need to upload a new build and re-submit it for TestFlight review before it will be available for external testers.  You don't need to submit it for full App Store review.  Ensure your new build addresses all of the issues raised in your TestFlight rejection.  To submit for TestFlight review, go to your external testers group and make the new build available to that group.

Answer (score 2):

You have to compile another build with different number and upload it again.

But before doing that i have to tell you: **an external testing with TestFlight requires a mostly complete app**.

Apple TestFlight documents for external testing:

> When you add the first build of your app to a group, the build gets sent to beta app review to make sure it follows the **App Store Review Guidelines**.

This means you have to pass [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) which is basically means your app should be good enough to release in the **AppStore**.